# QR Code Scanner Integration with C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I am writing one WPF application(MVVM) which needs to read data from QR Code Images using QR Code Scanner(Model: Symbol DS4308 - USB to connect with desktop). I googled for the same and identified that we can read QR Data using Textbox and it works. But my application won't have a textbox to capture the QR Code data but I need to get the scanner to provide the Event once scanning is done.

I tried with notepad and scanner writes the scanned values to it when scanning QR Code.

Is there any generic open source libraries to get the scanner events?

Comment: The scanner connected, from your description, seems to work like a keyboard. So, I suggest listening to KeyPressed on your UI, or using WindowsSDK (User32 dlls), to listen for keyboard pressed events. This is just a suggestion.

Comment: From my experience, all scanners act like a keyboard. They will enter the barcode/QR code as text and hit enter. You don't need a textbox to store the value, as @LupuSilviu has already suggested you can listen for keypresses

Comment: @p3tch, some scanners can run in managed mode, and via an SDK, you can control how the scanner behaves. But here, it seems he has a scanner in unmanaged mode, that is why the solution with KeyPress should work.

Comment: Maybe I've just been using cheap scanners :-)

There seems to be a C# .NET example for your scanner here https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/scanner-sdk-for-windows.html @Nithy

Comment: Thanks @ Lupu Silviu...I have downloaded and used the appropriate SDK for my scanner and i can get the OnScanDetected event...Thanks for all for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't worked with the 4308 specifically, but I program Symbol scanners at work so I'm familiar with them.

First of all, forget about keyboard mode. It's handy for scanning directly into documents etc but it sounds like you want to read the scanner directly. If so, go to the [DS4308 data sheet](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/barcode-scanners/ds4308-prg-en.pdf) and scan in the barcode in section 6-6 for "Simple COM Port Emulation". This will cause the scanner to now appear as a serial device, which you can then read with the C# SerialPort class:

```
this.Scanner = new SerialPort(this.SymbolPort);
this.Scanner.BaudRate = 9600;
this.Scanner.DataReceived += Scanner_DataReceived;
this.Scanner.Open();
.
.
.
private void Scanner_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    var len = this.Scanner.BytesToRead;
    var bytes = new byte[len];
    this.Scanner.Read(bytes, 0, len);
    var str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
    // do something with str here
}
```

If you want to make your app really user friendly then you can also determine which COM port to use programatically using the device PID and VID. To get the PID/VID just go to device manager and check the properties for the device. To find the COM port use the code on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350340/identify-com-port-using-vid-and-pid-for-usb-device-attached-to-x64), although that will search all devices installed on the system irrespective of whether or not they're actually plugged in so you'll want to cross-check it against SerialPort.GetPortNames().

Comment: I have made scanner as serial device also implemented the above code but i am not getting the Scanner_DataReceived event get fired when scanning the QR code. For more info about my implementation i created the new serialport object(_serialPortScanner = new SerialPort()) and event _serialPortScanner.DataReceived += _serialPortScanner_DataReceived; But the event is not fired when scanning the QR code.

Comment: Have you tried testing it with another serial terminal application? Putty is a good one, and will tell you right away whether the problem is the with scanner config or your code.

Comment: I have downloaded the SDK for the scanner and used to get the OnScanDetected event. Thanks a lot @Mark Feldman