# How to find com port location information in c#

Tags: c#, serial-port, location, wmi

I'm looking for the Location of com ports as shown in the Device Manager window.

For instance my COM1 Location is "on Intel(R) Z77 Express Chipset LPC Controller - 1E44"

I've listed the WMI Properties and SystemProperties for Win32_PnPEntity and Win32_SerialPort and it's not there.
I also searched the registry for the classID, found multiple entry, but no location.

Comment: [Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837985/getting-serial-port-information)

Comment: [another related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350340/identify-com-port-using-vid-and-pid-for-usb-device-attached-to-x64)